# Assigning a particular no of cores to a Weblogic instance

Tags: solaris, weblogic

Using virtualization we have built LDOMS in a single Solaris box, where each LDOM has 8 Cores and 12 GB of RAM. We have a Weblogic app server instance (managed server) running on this LDOM where we have many applications deployed on it. Average CPU Utilisation rate is 11%, Hence we are planning to do Vertical Scaling, Where we will add one more Weblogic appserver (managed server) instance running in the same LDOM with all the applications deployed on the first Weblogic instance also deployed on this new weblogic instance since they are part of the same cluster.

My question is that how can i assign 4 cores to the ALSB Instance 1 (already existing managed server instance) and assign 4 cores to the new ALSB instance 2 (instead of ALSB Instance 1 having all the 8 Cores for processing),
1) Is this solution feasible?
2) If feasible, how to achieve it?  (How can I assign a set of cores to each Weblogic appserver instance?)

Thanks a lot for your solutions in advance, please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea, why limit instances, WL is designed to balance threads across multiple instances and multiple cores. If you really want to hardwire instances then just put each on in a separate domain - but I still think it's a bad idea. What if instance 1 could really use a 5th core and instance 2 is sat doing nothing?

Comment: Thanks for the Info. Suppose we have a loadbalancer which balances load across this 2 ALSB instances in a Round Robin Fashion. During heavy load we will have a good and equivalent response time if we allocate each ALSB instance with 4 Cores, if we dont allocate then, it may happen that one instance may take up more Cores for processing while another may take up lesser cores, which means that there will be a significant performance difference between the 2 ALSB instances. Please let me know your thoughts on the same,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [project](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-1592/rmtaskproj-2.html) for each WL environment and assign CPU cores to it.